# Disabling ctrl F it is not working on first keypress of ctrl F in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

on first key press ctrl f not working code

```
if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Although you may be able to find a foolproof way to disable the CTRL-F shortcut that most browsers have for find, what if the user changes the shortcut, or clicks on the Find option through their browser's menu? More plainly, what are you attempting to accomplish by attempting to disable the Find function?

Comment: window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) 
    { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});this is not working in chrome only on first keypress

Comment: And why, exactly, do you want to complicate your users' lives?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) 
    { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

You can use this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/seangransee/Disable-CTRL-F-jQuery-plugin) as well.

Comment: tried above code but not working on first time key press

Comment: @Sandhya:- Which browser you are using?

Comment: using chrome,mozillla,IE9